# PHP uploading multiple files and save their path into a single row in DB

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, for-loop

i been looking around and didnt found a solution that fits my needs.
so lets cut to the chase.

SCENARIO: User will fill some text forms, the input of those forms will be stored into a database table (the text input are working and stores into database just fine), in the same form the user will upload 7 files and the paths of the files will be stored in the same table in diferent columns say image1 image2 image3 etc, but in the same row, so when the id of that row is needed the file paths will be retrieved also but im unable to build the query to insert the paths into database, ive managed store only one file and store its path into the database but im struggling with the multiple files, i just dont know how to check if the for loop has finished and how to build the query to insert all upladed file's paths into a single row in their respective columns.

Server is running PHP and postgreSQL

thanks in advance and hope you can help me!

```
  <?php
  include '../include/dbase.php';
  $result = '';
  if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
   $nombre = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
   $ntemporal = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
   $tipo = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
   $tamaño = $_FILES['upload']['size'];
   $error = $_FILES['upload']['error'];
   $file_name_all = '';
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++)
     {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
           if ($tmpFilePath != "")
             {
               $path = "../imagenes/propiedades/";
               $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
               $size = $_FILES['upload']['size'][$i];

               list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
               $file= time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
               $info = pathinfo($file);
               $filename = $file.".".$ext;
               if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload'['tmp_name'][$i],   $path.$filename))
               {
                  //my guess is an if check here to see if for 
         loop has finished all the uploads, and if returns true a try and 
      catch with the sql query to upload  only the path of each file the 
       row containing all other user input text.
               }
         }
           }
           }
          ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to save the file in a directory like files/$id_user/.. and the names in the database.

You can make a table for files;
table files with id_user + file_name for example.

If you want all in a same table, you can put all the file's names separated with comma or ; and after select them and explode for have them in array..

In your code, it's better to use ' than ", because php will try to find variables inside the " " .. and lost time for nothing...

```
$filename = $file.'.'.$ext; $filename = $file.".".$ext;;
```

If you write:

```
$test = 'hello';
echo 'i tell you $test'; => i tell you $test
echo "i tell you $test"; => i tell you hello
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, im used to use ' ' rarher than " ", find it easer to use concatenation when using variables, sometimes i get confused when building queries which require "". thanks for your advice, but im looking for a way to have the file paths in different columns.

Comment: So, in your table, you masu make X columns for X files. and save the files or the files names in each one.

Answer (score 0):

In your table, make column file_0, file_1, ....
and after, you can save in your table like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload'['tmp_name'][$i],   $path.$filename))
           {
          $sql = "UPDATE `your_table` SET `file_$i` = '$path.$filname' WHERE `id` = '$id_user'";
//execute your $sql
           }
```